# ReaderWriterLock that allows starvation

Tags: c#, .net, readerwriterlockslim

The following code does not complete, because second reader (tRead2) cannot acquire lock.

```
ReaderWriterLockSlim rw = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

var tRead1 = Task.Run
    (
        () => rw.EnterReadLock()
    );

var tWrite = Task.Run
    (
          () =>
          {
              Thread.Sleep(1000);
              rw.EnterWriteLock();
          }
    );


var tRead2 = Task.Run
    (
        () =>
        {

            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            rw.EnterReadLock();
        }
    );

Task.WaitAll(tRead1, tRead2);
```

I didn't expect this situation, I thought that since writer (tWrite) cannot get the lock, then the tRead2 would be allowed to do that (and tWrite will wait till all read-mode locks are released). I interpret this unexpected behavior as a way to disallow starvation of writer.

Is there any synchronization structure that would allow tRead2 to get the lock (even if tWrite might be starved)?

Comment: Note that it is described on msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx *A thread that tries to enter read mode blocks if there are threads waiting to enter write mode or if there is a single thread in write mode.* and *Blocking new readers when writers are queued is a lock fairness policy that favors writers.*

Comment: *cannot acquire lock* How do you experience this?

Comment: @Andreas: The code does not complete. Also, when stopped while debugging the thread that tRead2 is "riding on" hangs on rw.EnterReadLock() line.

Comment: You could use `TryEnterWriteLock` for the writer with a time out, task delay & retry on failure.